# java.lang.NumberFormatException: FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, testng, numberformatexception

I'm trying to read test data from excel and got the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "K1101.00"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(XSSFCell.java:197)
at utility.excel_reader.getCellData(excel_reader.java:151)
at utility.Utility.getData(Utility.java:164)
at testCases.FinCalculator.inputValue(FinCalculator.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
row 3 or column 10 does not exist  in xls
```

I'm using formula in CELL in my excel:
https://www.screencast.com/t/eepp6nWy571

My excel function (returns the data from a cell), if cell is as text then it works without problem:

```
// returns the data from a cell
public String getCellData(String sheetName,int colNum,int rowNum){
    try{
        if(rowNum <=0)
            return "";
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
    if(index==-1)
        return "";

    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
    if(row==null)
        return "";
    cell = row.getCell(colNum);
    if(cell==null)
        return "";

    if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
        return cell.getStringCellValue();
    else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC || cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA ){
        String cellText  = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
           // format in form of M/D/YY
           double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();

           Calendar cal =Calendar.getInstance();
           cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
                cellText =
                    (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
                    cellText = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 + "/" +
                               cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                               cellText;
                    }

                return cellText;
           }else if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                return "";
           else
                return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
           }
           catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "row "+rowNum+" or column "+colNum +" does not exist  in xls";
           }
}
```

Comment: I think the message is clear. `K1101.00` is not a number

Comment: And I'm using this formula in CELL
=CONCATENATE("K";B3;".00")
How it possible to read this cell?

Comment: How it possible to read every cell as String?

Answer (score 0):

No one help me.
And I resolved my problem.

I did cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); before reading the string value, which solved the problem regardless of how the user formatted the cell.